# How to check if there is any changes in line items on after submit?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have Po.
I want to check if the item lines have changed on after submit

```
 function onAction(context) {
        var newRec = context.newRecord;
        var oldRec = context.oldRecord;


        var newCount = newRec.getLineCount({
            sublistId: 'item'
        });

        var oldCount = oldRec.getLineCount({
            sublistId: 'item'
        });

        if (newCount != oldCount) {
            log.debug('result', 'true')
        } else {
            log.debug('result', 'false')
        }


    }

    return {
        onAction: onAction
    }
```

I did it with count line but I want also to check if there any changes in the line and not only the number of the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to compare each field you care about on each line.  Here's an example function that returns true/false if any lines were changed by comparing line count, then item, quantity and rate for each line.  You can modify it to meet your needs.

Using `some()` this way, the first field on the first line that is different will stop the comparison and return `true`.

```js
function linesChanged(context) {
    const fields = ['item', 'quantity', 'rate'];

    const oldRecord = context.oldRecord;
    const newRecord = context.newRecord;
    const oldLineCount = oldRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
    const newLineCount = newRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });

    if (oldLineCount !== newLineCount) {
        return true;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < newLineCount; i++) {
        var lineChanged = fields.some(field => {
            const oldValue = oldRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: field, line: i });
            const newValue = newRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: field, line: i });

            return oldValue !== newValue;
        });

        if (lineChanged) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```